# Any way to prevent emacs key bindings to bug in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, emacs, key-bindings

I'm wondering if I'm the only one struggling (i.e. failing) to keep the emacs key bindings working in Eclipse.

I set them. It works fine. The it stops working fine. Some keys still work, others don't. I find myself in a kind of weird quantum state of uncertain key-binding setup superposition. Some key bindings from the standard set work, some from the emacs set work, some things I can achieve with neither set of bindings.

I'm the only one to experience this? I've seen this on at least 4 computers in the past few months.

I set key bindings back to standard set. Sometimes it works. I use the reset to defaults button. Try to set it back to emacs. Doesn't work. Pressing the apply button between the different steps or not... Drives me crazy.

On some computers, the bindings are just whatever. Can only save using the mouse, C-d and C-k don't work to delete/cut lines, most emacs keys still work but back to C-space for auto-completion, etc.

Anyone knows what can cause this? How to prevent it? Am I pressing some key binding key-bindings by mistake?

Comment: What version of eclipse are you using? I am recently having trouble with it, because the "emacs" scheme randomly gets activated, but i want the default scheme. But i'm still using 3.5...

Comment: Yeah, there's clearly a few big problems with the key binding schemes. I have somewhere between 5 and 10 setups... pretty sure they're all Indigo or Juno. I try to keep up with the versions as much as possible. Didn't notice a difference between versions so far...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the Ctl-K, Ctl-D commands: after doing an upgrade (I forget whether it was Eclipse itself or the Android plugin) I saw Eclipse offering a little pop up menu on both these keys, offering to do either the correct Emacs command or some completely unrelated command. So, for example, Ctl-D offered to either delete the next character (correct) or delete the line (incorrect).

After some poking around in the key bindings (Windows>Preferences>General>Keys), I discovered that sure enough, someons in the Eclipse project supplied these wrong bindings in addition to the correct ones. So I deleted the incorrect bindings and left the correct ones.

So I thought I would be out of the woods at this point. But I also discovered that I had to add the correct binding back in a couple of times before it would stick.

Look for Cut to End of Line under the Command column and make sure it has Ctl-K when Editing Text and in the Text Editing Category. The same for Delete Next (which means next character). But make sure Ctl-D does NOT show up for the Delete Line Command.

Test it out in an editor window; if it fails, go edit the bindings again, test again, repeat until it sticks, making sure you click Apply after editing the bindings.